# Else statement "syntax error on token else"

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm writing a class that allows me to set up buttons for incrementing or decrementing numbers. The code for implementing the listener is below, but it's not liking my else statement for some reason:

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    if (event.getSource() == up)
        count++;
        label.setText("Value: " + count);
    else
        count--;
        label.setText("Value: " + count);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to surround the code blocks with `{` `}`.

Comment: That's why not using accolades is asking for problems.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: the [Latin/French](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accolade) name of the beast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Java `if` without a brace is only for one line. So your current code is equivalent to

```
if (event.getSource() == up) {
    count++;
}
label.setText("Value: " + count);
else {
    count--;
}
label.setText("Value: " + count);
```

Use braces.

```
if (event.getSource() == up) {
    count++;
    label.setText("Value: " + count);
} else {
    count--;
    label.setText("Value: " + count);
}
```

**OR**

```
if (event.getSource() == up) 
    count++;
else
    count--;
label.setText("Value: " + count);
```

**OR** [Conditonal Operator `? :`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) (aka [ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation))

```
count += (event.getSource() == up) ? 1 : -1;
label.setText("Value: " + count);
```